# Why does spring invokes so many methods before a method of a spring bean has been invoked?

Tags: java, spring

Suppose I specified a class into a spring config as follows:

```
<bean id="playerAccountDao" class="com.prcj.db.dao.PlayerAccountDaoImpl" scope="prototype">
    <property name="playerDao" ref="playerDao" />
</bean>

<bean id="commonPlayerDao" class="com.prcjcommons.db.dao.PlayerDaoImpl" scope="prototype">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="siteSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

In the config above I injected that bean into a `playerAccountDao` instance and if I try to invoke a method of the `playerDao` bean from the `playerAccountDao` there are some methods are being invoked:

```
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 57  
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 606  
AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 310 
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint() line: 182  
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 149  
TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 106   
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 171  
JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 204   
$Proxy151.selectRecordList(Long, Integer, PlayerStatus, UserCategory, Date, Date, int, int) line: not available
```

Why does `spring` do that? Why dont it just invoke that `DAO` method directly?

Comment: Spring provides AOP features, that's why you such stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me flip this around: why do **you** ever write methods that call other methods, instead of just changing variables directly?

It's just another form of indirection.  IoC is potentially very complicated, and Spring has a lot of features to make things nice(r) for the user, so it has a lot of situations to support.  Having these different invocation strategies and interceptors means that they can avoid duplication, sharing the common aspects while allowing different behaviour.

If they just invoked the DAO method, then most of their feature set couldn't be supported.